# Problem with array and pipe

Tags: tables, environments

I try to make my own environment with the package `array` and use `>{...}`. When the descriptor begins with a pipe "|", I have a problem : `! Package array Error: >{..} at wrong position: token ignored.`. I try to use `\expandafter` or `\@ifnextchar`, in vain.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter
\newcount\c@untligne
\def\numligne{\ifnum\c@untligne<\@ne\relax%
              \else
                    \the\c@untligne%
              \fi\global\advance\c@untligne\@ne}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{mytabular}[1]{\begin{tabular}{>{\numligne}#1}}{\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{mytabular}{c|c} % here when |c|c|
\hline
    row & column\\
    & ligne \\ 
    & ligne\\ 
\hline 
\end{mytabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `>{}` does nothing at all, except producing an error when `#1` starts with `|`.

Comment: @egreg, I know, I have a macro in `>{}` but not necessary for MWE, I want to be able du use | in first place in argument of *mytable*

Comment: @nikopol you might add the command to your MWE (or at least say what you want to do)! This way someone might think of a more robust way of doing that!

Comment: @Skillmon, I edit my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to examine the argument for a leading `|`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcounter{rowcount}
\newcommand{\numberrow}{%
  \ifnum\value{rowcount}>0
    \therowcount
  \fi
  \stepcounter{rowcount}%
}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{mytabular}[1]
  {\mytabular@look#1\@nil}
  {\end{tabular}\setcounter{rowcount}{0}}
\newcommand{\mytabular@look}{%
  \@ifnextchar|{\mytabular@look@i}{\mytabular@look@ii}%
}
\def\mytabular@look@i#1#2\@nil{%
  \begin{tabular}{|>{\numberrow}#2}%
}
\def\mytabular@look@ii#1\@nil{%
  \begin{tabular}{>{\numberrow}#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{mytabular}{cc}
\hline
    row & column\\
    & ligne \\ 
    & ligne\\ 
\hline 
\end{mytabular}

\bigskip

\begin{mytabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
    row & column\\
    & ligne \\ 
    & ligne\\ 
\hline 
\end{mytabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's what I want to do, without success. Thx

Comment: Is there a way to do the same with `\expandafter` before `>{}`?

Comment: @nikopol No: with `array` no expansion is performed on the argument to `tabular`.